# Finding the literacy rate percentage for each state and plotting on map

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to find  the literacy rate percentage for each state and plot on the map

In the column named Literate/Gender Im trying to calculate literate persons/illiterate persons so that i can get a percentage for each state and then put the same field in map as a color.Since im new to tableau ill appreciate help.Thanks
Column name TRU is Total(Total = Rural + Urban) so fitler for Total only

Data Source : 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9BxqNlLKxJtX1BpSzliVk9RWE0

Answer (score 0):

Hope all is well.  I've calculated the percentage against the total. I'm sending the two data samples. Please let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Sorry I can't send a screenshot from the tableau file as I don't have 10 positive in reputation (I've just joined the forum)

```
Area Name                   Literate/Gender         Percentage  Total

ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS   Illiterate Persons        22.68%    345,200
ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS   Literate Persons          77.32%    1,177,124

ANDHRA PRADESH              Illiterate Persons        40.23%    136,096,068
ANDHRA PRADESH             Literate Persons           59.77%    202,227,040

ARUNACHAL PRADESH           Illiterate Persons        44.64%    2,470,888
ARUNACHAL PRADESH           Literate Persons          55.36%    3,064,020

ASSAM                       Illiterate Persons        38.54%    48,110,396
ASSAM                       Literate Persons          61.46%    76,711,908
```

===========================================================================

```
Area Name                    Literate/Gender            Percentage

ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS     Illiterate Females       12.56%
ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS     Illiterate Males         10.11%
ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS     Literate Females         34.13%
ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS     Literate Males           43.19%

ANDHRA PRADESH                Illiterate Females       23.45%
ANDHRA PRADESH                Illiterate Males         16.78%
ANDHRA PRADESH                Literate Females         26.37%
ANDHRA PRADESH                Literate Males           33.40%
```

The way I've done it is:

1- Exclude the Literate and gender column you're not going to use (ex: in the first one, I excluded everything excepts persons).

2- Table calculations with Total column

> `sum([Total])/WINDOW_SUM(SUM([Total]))`

Comment: Im not sure what window sum will do but many thanks for your help. I ll use this as reference to research more on google

Comment: Hi, `Window sum` will give you the sum of the range you select.

`WINDOW_SUM(expression, [start, end])`

In your example, we will add up the total within each specific dimension. The start and end in the formula is each dimension (area Name in your case). Every time the dimension changes, the formula will start a new sum.

I'm sending a link to tableau library http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_tablecalculation.html     -- Hope it's useful

Comment: Hi @Kapil, please let me know if you  would need extra help.  Thanks

Comment: Hi thanks for the information Juanma. That was useful

Comment: You're welcome.  Please feel free to mark the question as answered if you think it's completed.